# In which specific scenarios does MoveIt initialize a separate node with the name `\move_group_commander_wrappers_...`?

Tags: ros, gazebo, moveit

I am trying to use MoveIt Python interface to send commands to my robot simulated in Gazebo Environment.

In scenario 1, when I launch the gazebo world (using launch file) and spawn my robot, the `rosnodes` created are as follows:

```
/controller_spawner
/gazebo
/move_group
/rosout
```

However, when I use a python script and launch the gazebo world, followed by spawning the robot and initializing the MoveIt interface, an additional `rosnode` is also created as:

`/move_group_commander_wrappers_1659372280293177942`

On doing `rosnode info /move_group_commander_wrappers_1659372280293177942`, I get the following output:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Node [/move_group_commander_wrappers_1659372280293177942]
Publications: 
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]

Subscriptions: 
 * /clock [rosgraph_msgs/Clock]

Services: 
 * /move_group_commander_wrappers_1659372280293177942/get_loggers
 * /move_group_commander_wrappers_1659372280293177942/set_logger_level


contacting node http://100.71.110.30:41023/ ...
ERROR: Communication with node[http://100.71.110.30:41023/] failed!
```

**Can someone please explain why this new node is created and how can this avoided?**

Note, in both cases, the MoveIt python interface class initialization is done as follows:

```
rospy.init_node('my_robot', anonymous=False)
moveit_commander.roscpp_initialize(sys.argv)
```

Comment: **UPDATE** Since I was using another ROS node to initialize this `my_robot` node, it seemed to crash until I used: `rospy.init_node('my_robot', anonymous=False, disable_signals=True)` where `disable_signals=True` is important as Python does not allow signals to be register unless it is from the main thread.

Comment: It would still be very helpful to understand the reason why the `move_group_commander_wrappers_*` node is initialized at the first place.